# Update boolean property within object array before pushing new item in Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an action called `ADD_USER_PICTURE` that whenever called, I simply add a new picture to the array.
But, there's a little trick, these picture objects that I add, has some boolean property, that tells what picture is `Enabled` to be the avatar for the profile. That means that I need to modify the last current `picture.isEnabled` from `true` to `false` so the new one will be the avatar.

This is my action:

```
case ADD_USER_PICTURE:
    return {
       ...state,
       userInfo: {
         ...state.userInfo,
         userPictures: [...state.userInfo.userPictures, action.picture]
       }
}
```

I guess I have to add a map and iterate but through userPictures like this but I'm not sure about how to do it with Redux and due to immutability.

I'm thinking on something like this:

```
userPictures.map((picture) => {
    if (picture.isAvatar) {
       picture.isEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

It would be way faster to put all in false and that's it instead of searching. I don't want to create a 2nd action just for this.

Any help on how to adapt this to Redux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create another action that will deal with this logic, then you can simply do this within the reducer, though I wouldn't recommend it.

But your reducer action type case for `ADD_USER_PICTURE` would look something like this.

```
case ADD_USER_PICTURE:

  const { userPictures } = state.userInfo;

  // Map through and set isEnabled to false for other pictures
  let updatedUserPictures = userPictures.map(picture => ({
    ...picture,
    isEnabled: false,
  }));

  // Insert the new profile picture within array, and set isEnabled to true
  updatedUserPictures = [
    ...updatedUserPictures,
    { ...action.pictures, isEnabled: true },
  ];

  return {
    ...state,
    userInfo: {
      ...state.userInfo,
      userPictures: updatedUserPictures,
    },
  };
```

**UPDATE:** *If you chose to go about implementing it the way I mentioned below, this is how your actions would look like:*
[image: Action Functions]

*And this is how your component would look like:*
[image]

Comment: So you recommend having 2 actions for this? one for set all to false and another to put one more item? Why this is "wrong" or not recommended? Thanks for replying.

Comment: It most definitely isn't wrong to do it this way, the reason why I wouldn't recommend it is because then you've got business logic within a reducer file. Ideally you want to keep all of your business logic within an action.

I would have an action called `updateUserPofilePic` that would have all the logic for setting the new picture's `isEnabled` attribute to `true`, it would then dispatch an action called `updateUserProfilePicSuccess`; which would take in an argument of `userPictures` and would be a pure function that returns an object with `type: ADD_USER_PICTURE ` and `data`.

Comment: wow D: i'm completely lost now hahaha i started with redux like 2 days ago. :( can you dispatch an action from within another action? or you say externally? like from my component i call one, and then the other?

Comment: Aaah! haha no worries! But yeah, so I'm not sure how you've integrated with redux within your application. 

Though whichever functions you import within `mapDispatchToProps` all have a `dispatch` argument injected into it.

So say you have a component called `Header`. And then when you're using redux's `connect` High Order Component, it takes in 4 arguments https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect (I'll just focus on 2). The first is `mapStateToProps` and the second is `mapDispatchToProps`. You can then write a function called `updateUserProfilePic`...continued

Comment: ... and the function declaration would look something like this
 `const updateUserProfilePic = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Some logic here...
  // Use dispatch here to dispatch other actions
  dispatch(someOtherAction());
}`


To learn more about `getState` : https://redux.js.org/api/store#getState

Comment: Thanks for the hint, man! I will try to implement it that way then. This is how i use it on my mapDispatchToProps: onAddUserPicture: (picture) => dispatch(addUserPicture(picture)). So within updateUserProfilePic, i would dispatch also addUserPicture? :o that means i would need to pass picture object to updateUserProfilePic i guess.

Comment: Check my answer, I updated the reply post to show how you would go about implementing it.

Comment: I can't make it work on my redux setup. I got an actions.js containing all the actions, then actionTypes.js, with the types, then the userReducer which is the basic switch and checking for switch.type.
The updatedPictureSuccess where you set the type, should go to my reducer's switch, right? you pass "data" there. Now, i got this on my reducer

case ADD_USER_PICTURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                userInfo: {
                    ...state.userInfo,
                    userPictures: action.data
                }
            }

Comment: NICE! i ended up using your workaround but with redux-thunk and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear